# Abandoning wire in attic space

Tags: wiring, nec, remodeling

I'm in the US, and I have three recessed lights daisy-chained from a switch, and I want to take the last one (#3) out of service. I'm lowering the ceiling in this area, so converting it to a junction box is not really an option. The inspector also made it clear that simply capping off the (energized) wires in this new void space is not allowable.

Each fixture has a built-in junction box. #2's box has the line coming in from #1, and another wire going to #3, all connected with wire nuts in the box. In box #2, I've disconnected the wire going to #3, wired everything back up and verified that #1 and #2 work and that the wires going to #3 are cold.

That leaves me with dead wire from a dead fixture (#3) going into a live junction box at #2. What more do I need to do? Can I cap off the now-dead wires in box #2 and leave everything in place?

Comment: What country is this in (different countries will have different regs)?

Comment: Thanks, @SpacePhoenix. I've added #nec and clarified that I'm in the US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no code saying you cannot leave de-energized wires anywhere you want to. When the inspector said that "capping off the wires in this new void space is not allowable" he probably said it with the assumption that they would still be energized. I think it would still be responsible to label them with a tag saying something like "dead circuit, do not energize".

If I'm wrong then the Sparkys on this forum will surely correct me.

Comment: Yeah, the inspector's comment was regarding still-connected wires. Edited question to clarify.

Comment: There is this, but it's specific to **communications** cable (telephone/network/etc.) as of NEC 2002 removal of **the accessible portion** of abandoned cable is required unless it's **contained in a raceway.** And even there you can simply label the ends as a spare cable rather than remove it - spare is not abandoned (but so obsolete it's of no practical use is not really spare, either.)

Answer (score 1):

In Australia the code requires disconnected wires to be removed.